# Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length exception

Tags: vb.net

am getting the above exception while swaping Items in the list(lstRoutePriority).PFB my code

```
if (lstRoutePriority.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
   //Swap the two items 
   idTemp = (ItemData)lstRoutePriority.Items[lstRoutePriority.SelectedIndex];
   lstRoutePriority.Items[lstRoutePriority.SelectedIndex] = 
   lstRoutePriority.Items[lstRoutePriority.SelectedIndex-1];
   lstRoutePriority.Items[lstRoutePriority.SelectedIndex-1] = idTemp;
}
```

can someone tell me how to fix this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this

```
lstRoutePriority.SelectedIndex > 0
```

by

```
lstRoutePriority.SelectedIndex >= 0
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

I think the

```
lstRoutePriority.SelectedIndex > 0
```

constraint is correct. Otherwise

```
lstRoutePriority.SelectedIndex-1
```

could be negative. I think you also should check whether SelectedIndex isn't larger than the length of the list minus 1.